# Does ubuntu have elfdump?

Tags: command-line

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m8b/index.html

I see SunOS has elfdump. Does ubuntu have it as well? I can not find this command.

Comment: We have `readelf`. Read `man readelf;man -k elf`.

Comment: @waltinator that sounds like an answer ;)